how to add multiple email to sns subscription
I am trying to add multiple email address in cdk code for sns subscription but getting error as Invalid parameter email address. When i tried with one email address then it works without issue.
// Adding an SNS action and an email registration 
const notificationsTopic = new Topic(this, 'Topic'); 
numFailedJobsAlarm.addAlarmAction(new SnsAction(notificationsTopic));
notificationsTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription('rd@bak.de, ak@bak.de')); 

How can i add multiple email address in sns subscription ?

An SNS email subscription has a single email target. If you want to target more than one email, you need to create more than one subscription.
const emails = ['rd@bak.de', 'ak@bak.de'];

emails.forEach((email) => {
    notificationsTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription(email));
});


const emails = ['rd@bak.de', 'ak@bak.de']; the string between email has to be separated then it worked

Oh, of course! That was a brain fart on my part. Edited the answer.

Try This:
notificationsTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription('rd@bak.de'));
notificationsTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription('ak@bak.de'));
